# Is there a neomodel way of traversing a path given the root node?

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neomodel

I am trying to extract a path but using neomodel **without raw cypher**

How would u implement the equivalent of

`MATCH (n:node_class {reference: 'some_root_node_id'})-[:relationship*0..]-(m:node_class) SET m.property=n.property`

but in Neomodel code, without using raw cypher?

I tried using the `neomodel.match.Traversal` class but it seems to only return the first level related nodes, could there be a parameter I am unaware of?

```
class node_class(StructuredNode):
    reference = StringProperty()
    relationship = Relationship(node_class, 'relationship')
```